# Unable to login via Username/password and Microsoft Graph API, resource owner password credentials, Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I got error below by following steps below in [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-console-up-v2):

Step 1: Clone or download this repository

Step 2: (Optional) Register the sample with your Azure Active Directory tenant

Choose the Azure AD tenant where you want to create your applications

Register the client app (up-console)

Step 3: Configure the sample to use your Azure AD tenant

Run the app:

```
Enter your username
anyuser@outlook.com
Enter your password (no backspace possible)
*********
Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (NotAcceptable).
Press any key to exit
```

```
Enter your username
anyuser@msn.com
Enter your password (no backspace possible)
*********
Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (NotAcceptable).
Press any key to exit
```

I changed the setting in Supported account types to below, but got the same error

`Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox, Outlook.com)`

```
Enter your username
anyuser@outlook.com
Enter your password (no backspace possible)
*********
Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (NotAcceptable).
Press any key to exit
```

Any idea?

`anyuser@outlook.com` has admin permission

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you may be trying to use a personal Microsoft account. It will not work with this authentication flow.

The password grant (aka resource owner password credentials grant flow) only works with users who are Azure AD users, do not have MFA, and who are not federated. And the password must not have expired.

Comment: Thanks. What does it mean by 'federated'?

Comment: Any account that isn't originally from that Azure AD. On-prem AD accounts, personal MS accounts etc.

Comment: I tried it using my firm's account, which can be used to sign in azure portal, azure devops and office 365 etc, But this account still is not working? I am ware that my firm has a on-premise AD. What type is my firm's account? What account can be "originally from that Azure AD" as you said? can you give an example of this account? Sorry for the question. I am confused.

Comment: I mean a cloud-only account. Not an account synced from somewhere, nor an account where you are redirected to login at another provider (e.g. Microsoft accounts)

Comment: You said, "Not an account synced from somewhere". Most companies sync their employees to Azure Active Directory. Is it correct that they cannot use this ROPC for Azure AD?  ROPC for cloud-only account, is it correct that the usage of this feature is really narrow in practice. This renders this feature useless.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You shouldn't use it anyway, because of the security implications + being unable to use MFA.

Comment: so Microsoft team puts the restriction (cloud-only account) to limit the usage of it?